# What does a = b = c mean in sql?

Tags: sql, vertica

I see that it's possible to compose a query in vertica SQL where you compare between 3 parameters in the below way

```
select * from table1 a
join table2 b on ...
join table3 c on ...
where a.id = b.id = c.id
```

Is it equal to

```
select * from table1 a
join table2 b on ...
join table3 c on ...
where a.id = b.id and b.id = c.id
```

Or does it have a different meaning?

Comment: In most dialects of SQL, this would generate an error.  In some dialects of SQL (e.g. MySQL), it would mean:  `(a.id = b.id) = c.id`.  The first expression would evaluate to 1 (if the two ids are equal) or 0 or NULL.  In such databases, the overall expression would be rather meaningless.  I don't know what Vertica does on this matter, but I note that there are several other aspects of Vertica expression parsing that are similar to MySQL.

Comment: Interesting. Could you please show how the three tables have been joined? I mean JOIN TABLE2 b ON <what>?

Comment: I have tried to replicate your implicit join in the where clause but it doesn't work for me. Are your "id" columns booleans? What about sharing a complete reproducer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`b.id = c.id` will be evaluated first, and be equal to `true` or `false`.
This will then be compared to `a.id`, which can be boolean or a number equal to 0 or 1. If a.id is a number other than 0 or 1, you will get an error.

That been said, I think that's not the behavior you want :)